# Detect and prevent using bad memory blocks on a graphics card

Tags: windows, memory, graphics-card

Is there a tool that can detect and map bad memory blocks on a graphics card similar to a hard drive. E.g. some sort of windows driver that would reserve the bad memory blocks from the graphics card so that no other application can be allocated those memory blocks.

The graphics card only has 2 small memory blocks in close proximity that have failed. This failure has been stable for at least a year. It seems a shame to throw away an otherwise perfectly working graphics card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no such thing exists.  The graphics card hardware, including memory, is abstracted from the OS.  There is no way for the OS to interface with the graphics card, except through the driver.  In theory it is *possible* for the manufacturer to make such a tool, but why would they?  They want you to be a new graphics card.